# $_FILES is not working with Angular.js $http post

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I had one issue.I can not store image file inside the local folder using Angular.js.Please check my code below.

> index.html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile" ng-controller="imgController">
<form  name="form">
<label for="bannerimage" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Banner Image</label>
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="bannerimage" id="bannerimage" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100" ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}" custom-on-change="uploadFile" multiple>
<label for="bannerimage" accesskey="B" ><span class="required">*</span> View Image</label>
<div style="padding-bottom:10px;" ng-repeat="step in stepsModel">
<img ng-src="{{step}}" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;">
</div>
<div><input type="button" id="btn" ng-click="submitImage();" value="Upload" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

The below code is my controller file.

```
var app=angular.module('testImage',['ngFileUpload']);
app.controller('imgController',function($scope,$http,$filter){
    $scope.submitImage=function(){
        var today = $filter('date')(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
        var newpath=today+"_"+ $scope.file.name;
        var arrFile={'name':newpath,'size':$scope.file.size,'type':$scope.file.type};
        var data={'image':arrFile}
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"upload.php",
            data:data,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log('res',response);
        },function errorCallback(response) {
        });
    }
    $scope.stepsModel = [];
    $scope.uploadFile = function(event){
        console.log('event',event.target.files);
        var files = event.target.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         var file = files[i];
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded; 
             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
    };
    $scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.stepsModel.push(e.target.result);
    });
}
});
app.directive('customOnChange', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var onChangeHandler = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
      element.bind('change', onChangeHandler);
    }
  };
});
```

In the above code i am creating unique name for each image and i need when i will also save those images with therespective unique name.

> upload.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){    
    $errors= array();        
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
    $file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");        
    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
         $errors[]="image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"upload/".$file_name);
        echo " uploaded file: " . "images/" . $file_name;
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
else{
    $errors= array();
    $errors[]="No image found";
    print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

By using this php code i am getting always `No image found` message in the browser console.Please help me to do this.

Comment: doesn't look like you're using a valid enctype

Comment: plus, there are 2 different folder declarations here `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"upload/".$file_name);
        echo " uploaded file: " . "images/" . $file_name;`

Comment: Can you please make this correct so that it will work as per requirement.

Comment: What i got it can not move into `if` statement of php file.

Comment: add an enctype `<form  name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">` or `<form  name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`

Comment: You arent sending a file in your ajax request, all you are sending is metadata (ie name, size, type), you havent attached either your image dataURL or the actual image file to your data object.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Hay i did as per you but getting the same issue.

Comment: @PatrickEvans : Ok can you please edit your answer with my code ?

Comment: you need to replace your present header with this `headers: {enctype:'multipart/form-data'}` or add to it if it lets you. I know that is definitely required when uploading files.

Comment: plus make sure the folder you're wanting to upload to, has the correct permissions to write to it and is the correct folder and that it exists. check for errors.

Comment: Let me to check and i will conform you.

Comment: I really must go to bed now. @ me if you were successful. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97040/discussion-between-satya-and-fred-ii).